# Does a continuous function in $W^{1,p}$ for $p<n$ lie in $W^{1,n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded domain. Suppose that $f \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some specific $1<p<n$, and that $f$ is continuous.

Is it true that $f \in W^{1,n}_{loc}(\Omega)$?

(In "almost" the other direction, we know that if $f \in W^{1,p}$ for $p>n$ then it's continuous).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such self-improvement. Continuity adds nothing for Sobolev regularity purposes.

Consider functions of the form $u(x)=|x|\sin (|x|^{-a})$, $u(0)=0$, where $a>0$. The domain can be the unit ball $B$.

The function $u$ is continuous on $B$ and  smooth on $B\setminus\{0\}$. The gradient of $u$ is 
$$
\nabla u(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}\sin (|x|^{-a}) - \frac{a x}{|x|^{1+a}}\cos (|x|^{-a}) $$
which implies $|\nabla u(x)| = O(|x|^{-a})$, and $|\nabla u(x)| \sim  |x|^{-a}$ most of the time, when the cosine term is bounded away from $0$.

Therefore, $u\in W^{1,p}(B)$ if and only if $p<n/a$. Choose $a>0$ as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. Do you have an idea how to formally prove your map $u$ lies in a Sobolev space? I see naively that your calculation of the differential $\nabla u$ is merely an application of the chain rule-$\nabla(fg)=f\nabla g+g \nabla f$. However, is it clear this works in the weaker setting of weak derivatives? (in particular, both maps, $f=|x|,g=\sin(|x|^{-a})$ are not classically smooth at the origin, so this is not for instance, the case of a $C^1$ function multiplied by a Sobolev function. I wonder if one can phrase some more general claim here, or just "prove by hand" .

Comment: [ACL characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Absolutely_continuous_on_lines_(ACL)_characterization_of_Sobolev_functions) says it's okay to use pointwise derivatives as long as ACL condition holds. The condition holds here, as the function is Lipschitz on every horizontal segment except one.